iOS Keyboard hides text field on iOS 17.3.1
I have an old Swift iOS application and when the user clicks on a field I have the code below to move the main view up. This works perfectly on an iPhone 6 (iOS 12.5.7). On an iPhone SE (iOS 17.3.1) the view seems to move down and then as the keyboard animates upwards the view moves with it back to its starting point. It happens quite quickly so I am guessing this is what is happening. The value for keyboardRect.height seems reasonable. Does anyone know how I can fix this situation?
  @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification){
    if isShowingKeyboard {
      return
    }
    let userInfo = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo!
    let navbarHeight = navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
    let keyboardRect : CGRect = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardRect.height
    isShowingKeyboard = true
  }

